# Reflection can't convert object

Tags: c#, reflection, casting, type-conversion

I want use reflection to dynamic to populate any class, but when this class has a property as other class I have encountered problem. in this example above I reproduce, a part of code to show same dificult. I can't convert object to address.

Can you help me?

```
public class Destinatary 
{
    public string DetinataryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }


}

public class Address
{
    public string Place { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Destinatary destinataryTest = new Destinatary();
        Type type = typeof(Destinatary);
        destinataryTest = GenerateDataSample(destinataryTest);

        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {destinataryTest.Name}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Place: {destinataryTest.Address.PostalCode}");
        Console.WriteLine($"City: {destinataryTest.Address.City.Name}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static T GenerateDataSample<T>(T classToWork)
    {
        Type typeToWork = typeof(T);
        object tipoInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeToWork);
        foreach (var classProperty in typeToWork.GetProperties())
        {

            if (classProperty.PropertyType.FullName.StartsWith("System."))
            {
                var propertyVal = RandomString(10,false ); 
                classProperty.SetValue(tipoInstance, propertyVal, null);
            }
            else
            {
                var instanceIntermediate = Activator.CreateInstance(classProperty.PropertyType);
                instanceIntermediate = GenerateDataSample(instanceIntermediate);                    
                classProperty.SetValue(tipoInstance, instanceIntermediate, null); //here there is a probleman (Cant convert Object to Address)

            }
        }
        return (T)tipoInstance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics are resolved at compile time, not at run time.

In this line

```
instanceIntermediate = GenerateDataSample(instanceIntermediate);
```

instanceIntermediate is an Address object, but the compiler here only knows that it is an object. So it calls GenerateDataSample which will construct an object in this line

```
object tipoInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeToWork);
```

To have GenerateDataSample create an instance of the type of the object classToWork, use

```
object tipoInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(classToWork.GetType());
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to convert the value? The object is already of type `Address` and the set method is declared as

```
public void SetValue (object obj, object value);
```

i.e., it accepts a variable of type `object`.

The problem occurs when calling `GenerateDataSample<T>()`, because `T` is determined at compile time and the compile time type of `instanceIntermediate` is `object`, therefore `GenerateDataSample` will always try to create an object of type `System.Object` for properties. Don't make `GenerateDataSample` generic.

Also, you don't actually need to pass an instance but only a type to `GenerateDataSample`.

```
private static object GenerateDataSample(Type typeToWork)
{
    object tipoInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeToWork);
    foreach (PropertyInfo classProperty in typeToWork.GetProperties()) {
        object propertyVal;
        if (classProperty.PropertyType == typeof(string)) {
            propertyVal = RandomString(10, false);
        } else {
            propertyVal = GenerateDataSample(classProperty.PropertyType);
        }
        classProperty.SetValue(tipoInstance, propertyVal);
    }
    return tipoInstance;
}
```

You can also create an overloaded generic version:

```
private static T GenerateDataSample<T>()
{
    return (T)GenerateDataSample(typeof(T));
}
```

Then you can create sample data with:

```
Destinatary destinataryTest = GenerateDataSample<Destinatary>();
```

Answer (score 0):

`var instanceIntermediate = Activator.CreateInstance(...` - on this line compile time type of `instanceIntermediate` is `object`. So when you call `GenerateDataSample(instanceIntermediate)` it is calling `GenerateDataSample<object>(instanceIntermediate)` and not `GenerateDataSample<Address>(instanceIntermediate)` as you probably expect.

Fix: since `GenerateDataSample` does not actually care about input parameter and only type - change it from generic to regular method taking type - `object GenerateDataSample(Type typeToWork)`